# pandas groupby complex numbers fails

Tags: python, pandas

UPDATE: here is a simplified version of the code (as requested) that produces the same error:

```
import numpy as np
line = [0,0,0,1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4]
x = [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]
y = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1]
number = np.arange(0, 120, 10)
cnumber = number +1j*0
FrData = [line, x, y, cnumber]
import pandas as pd
ToProcess = pd.DataFrame(data = zip(*(FrData)), index = FrData[0],
                         columns = ['line', 'x', 'y', 'cnumber'])
CleanData = ToProcess.groupby(['line', 'x', 'y'])['cnumber'].mean().reset_index()
```

which works, but gives me an error - data are no complex numbers anymore:

> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/nanops.py:496: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
>     x = float(x)

the error points to that part of the pandas code:

```
def _ensure_numeric(x):
if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
    if x.dtype == np.object_:
        x = x.astype(np.float64)
elif not (com.is_float(x) or com.is_integer(x)):
    try:
        x = float(x)
    except Exception:
        raise TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x))

return x
```

I can see, and I know, that the x.astype(np.complex) is missing - and I am pretty sure in a previous version of the pandas I had I changed that based on a posting (which I fail to find now) - I need to add it there, so it does not convert my complex numbers back to floats - 
any suggestions?

UPDATE
A temporary solution is to change the above described function in nanops.py, and replace x=float(x) to x=x.astype(np.complex), so the part of the code now is:

```
def _ensure_numeric(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
        if x.dtype == np.object_:
            x = x.astype(np.float64)
    elif not (com.is_float(x) or com.is_integer(x)):
        try:
            x = x.astype(np.complex)
        except Exception:
            raise TypeError('Could not convert %s to numeric' % str(x))

    return x
```

this worked for me, but I am not sure if it is a correct/complete solution

Comment: What's FRData... Would be useful if we could replicate this.

Comment: @AndyHayden I will provide some data later, the files are big, and there is a whole lot to bring them to this format - since I am kind of inexperienced it will take time to do it - but will do by tomorrow morning (US -ET time)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to real part of the complex numbers (numpy.real), unfortunately this doesn't play super nicely with pandas Series/DataFrame, so you need to apply back the indexes:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1 + 1j])

In [12]: s
Out[12]:
0    (1+1j)
dtype: complex128

In [13]: np.real(s)
Out[13]:
array([ 1.])

In [14]: pd.Series(np.real(s), s.index, name=s.name)
Out[14]:
0    1
dtype: float64
```